# Delete all rows that contain a specific string if another string was found in any row of another column for that string in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if the question is a little hard to understand.

Basically I have a sheet with multiple columns and rows of data with headings like so:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data 1 | type 2 | BAD1 |
| data 2 | type 2 | test |
| data 2 | type 3 | test |
| data 3 | type 4 | BAD3 |
| data 4 | type 1 | BAD2 |
| data 4 | type 5 | test |

I wish to remove all rows that contain a certain content in a certain column but I then also wish to remove all rows that contain another content in a different column once any row for that content has been found with the string.

For example remove all rows that contain either BAD1, BAD2 or BAD3
In the example Data 1 and Data 3 will be removed. Data 4 will also be removed but I wish to remove ALL rows of Data 4 once ANY row was found with bad in column c. In this case both Data 4 rows should be removed since one of them showed BAD2 in column c

I hope that makes sense

I have tried filtering like so:

```
Sub DeleteBAD()
  Dim v As Variant
  For Each v In Array("BAD1", "BAD2")
    Columns("F").Replace v, "#N/A", xlWhole, , True, , False, False
  Next
  Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

but I'm lost on how to get it to delete all of the other rows for criteria where Bad was found

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this mod. Essential to check only the active range of the sheet for the shorter run-time.

Modify columns' letter and offset distance to the actuals.

```
Sub DeleteBAD()
  Dim v As Variant
  lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  
  For Each v In Array("BAD1", "BAD2", "BAD3")
    Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Replace v, "#N/A", xlWhole, , True, , False, False
  Next
  For Each cell In Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Cells
     If IsError(cell) Then
       actualdata = cell.Offset(0, -2)
       For Each datcell In Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Cells
         If datcell = actualdata Then
           datcell.Offset(0, 2) = "#N/A"
         End If
       Next datcell
     End If
  Next cell
  Columns("C").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Matching Rows With a Twist

- Deletes all rows containing a unique value in column 1, if at least one of the corresponding cells in column 3 is equal to any string from a given list (focus on rows 6 and 7).

[image]

```vb
Sub DeleteMatchingRows()

    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 3
    Const UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    Dim Criteria() As Variant: Criteria = Array("bad1", "BAD2", "Bad3")

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = trg.Rows.Count - 1
    
    If rCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data found in range """ & trg.Address(0, 0) _
            & """ of sheet """ & ws.Name & """ of workbook """ _
            & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = trg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = drg.Columns(CRITERIA_COLUMN)
    
    Dim cIndices() As Variant: cIndices = Application.Match(crg, Criteria, 0)
    
    If Application.Count(cIndices) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matches found in range """ & crg.Address(0, 0) _
            & """ of sheet """ & ws.Name & """ of workbook """ _
            & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If rCount = 1 Then
        drg.Delete xlShiftUp
        GoTo ShowMessage
    End If
    
    Dim uData() As Variant: uData = drg.Columns(UNIQUE_COLUMN).Value
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If IsNumeric(cIndices(r, 1)) Then dict(CStr(uData(r, 1))) = Empty
    Next r
    
    trg.AutoFilter UNIQUE_COLUMN, dict.Keys, xlFilterValues
    
    drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete xlShiftUp
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
ShowMessage:
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Matching rows deleted.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```